# What is Spark's default cluster manager

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

When using PySaprk and getting the Spark Session using following statement:

```
 spark = SparkSession.builder
         .appName("sample-app")
         .getOrCreate()
```

app works fine but I am unsure which cluster manager is being with this spark session. Is it local or standalone. I read through the docs but no where I found this thing documented. They tell about what are standalone and local cluster managers but no mention of which is default option.

Comment: By default, if you don't specify any configuration, the Spark Session created using the SparkSession.builder API will use the local cluster manager. This means that the Spark application will run on the local machine and use all available cores to execute the Spark jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the multiple factors - is it submitted with the `spark-submit` that may have `--master` option specified, if the master is specified in the config file, etc.  All of this is described in the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).

If you just run this code as a Python script, then it will be `local[*]`, meaning that it will locally on all cores. You can check this by calling `spark.conf.get("spark.master")`

Comment: Is the default `local[*]`? I always assumed it was `local`

Comment: it could be different depending on the version, but I double checked before answering, and in the 3.3 it's `local[*]`